# How to fill a vector in c++ on initialisation

Tags: c++, vector

So i have this assignement for school and had to make a sort of table and i decide to do this like :

```
   string  na[11][6] = {{"2a",         "1b"},
                        {"3a",  "1b",  "2b"},
                        {"4a",  "2b",  "3b"},
                        {"5a",  "3b",  "4b"},
                        {"6a",  "4b",  "5b"},
                        {"7a",  "5b",  "6b"},
                        {"8a",  "6b",  "7b"},
                        {"9a",  "7b",  "8b"},
                        {"10a", "8b",  "9b"},
                        {"11a", "9b",  "10b"},
                        {       "10b", "11b"}};
```

So when  i went on coding it came to me that this it doesnt work with other parts of my code and i thought that maybe the best way was to use a vector.
but just

```
vector<vector<string>>  na = {{"2a",         "1b"},
                             {"3a",  "1b",  "2b"},
                             {"4a",  "2b",  "3b"},
                             {"5a",  "3b",  "4b"},
                             {"6a",  "4b",  "5b"},
                             {"7a",  "5b",  "6b"},
                             {"8a",  "6b",  "7b"},
                             {"9a",  "7b",  "8b"},
                             {"10a", "8b",  "9b"},
                             {"11a", "9b",  "10b"},
                             {       "10b", "11b"}};
```

but this doesnt work.
i have searched for a while now but i cant find anything that is close to this.
Do you guys have any idea?

if i do this it gives the error :

> 1   IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "std::vector>, std::allocator>>>"

on the first { after the = sign

Comment: What is the error you get? [For me, it works correctly.](http://ideone.com/71LaiQ)

Comment: That should work, unless your compiler doesn't support C++11.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You are missing a closing `>`.

Comment: i have the extra > in the code, i forgot to type it here

Comment: Intellisense errors _are not real errors_.  They're hints that _maybe_ something is an error, but sometimes _it lies_.   @herohuyongtao: More specifically, what year of Visual Studio?

Comment: You need MSVC 2013 for initializer lists to work. What is your version?

Comment: i use visual studio 2012 proffessional, that maybe it ....